# burninate [sql-server-administration]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

So a lot of times in the Sql-Server tag on Stack Overflow, people ask questions that are really about Database Administration, and not development.   And I or somebody else will usually vote to migrate the post to https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Today I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951104/sqldiag-issues-with-alwayson) that obviously is such a question, and it was even tagged with [sql-server-administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-administration).

Does it make sense to have such a tag on Stack Overflow when there's https://dba.stackexchange.com?  Might we either delete the tag, or have it automatically migrate or suggest-migrate the question to dba?

Comment: It seems like an off-topic tag that would be better handled on DBA.  With a grand total of 25 questions, 5 followers and no tag wiki, it should be easy to burninate.  Just (very quickly) glancing through the questions, it seems like most are probably a better fit on DBA or mistagged.  I vote for burnination.